# Share files on external hard disk via router?

Tags: networking, router, sharing

I have a TP Link W8951ND router, and it DOES NOT have a USB port. I would like to share files from an external hard disk over the LAN network, using this router. I was wondering if there was any way to do so.
(I don't want to use a computer to share files, I know how to do that, I want to share files directly from the HD without using a PC)

Comment: There are external disks that have a LAN port themselves.  That would be pretty much the only way to accomplish what you want.  Your hardware does not support hooking a USB external drive to your router, if your router, does not have a USB port.

Comment: You'll need NAS.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, he does not "need" a NAS. Incorrect information.

Comment: NAS = Network Attached Storage.  Note I said "NAS" not "*a* NAS".

Answer (score 1):

Not with your router directly. However they do make devices that are designed to create a NAS device out of connected USB drives. I have not used them, nor do I endorse any such device in particular, but just as an example, see this device:

http://www.addonics.com/products/nas40esu.php

I would gather it would be as simple as plugging in a couple of drives to this device and then hooking the device to your router with a patch cable. It would presumably receive an IP address and then be accessible via web browser or included software to configure attached drives in such a way that they can then be shared on the network.

Comment: In my curiosity I looked further at these devices and found a TP Link, if you like that brand and want to keep it across the board for your home, it is about half the price of the one i cited as an example in my answer but does not cite any NAS functionality however: http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4759_TL-PS310U.html

Comment: So in your comment on the question you say I'm giving incorrect information by suggesting that he needs network attached storage (NAS), and then you go on to suggest exactly that?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes my mistake, I misread your comment as "A NAS" as though you were telling him he will need to buy a NAS device for disks, etc. You did in fact just say NAS. Thank you for pointing that out. My apologies.

Comment: No problems, I was just confused by the scenario. :)